# What version of clonezilla live should I use?

Tags: clonezilla

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal Quetzal 64 bits, on a different partition Windows Vista 32 bits (brought this factory and I is useful for programs that bring).

I want to clone both OS with clonezilla live, but in the Clonezilla-live page appears me different download options, and I dont know what of all options are correct and make a right choice for optimal cloning of these operating systems, the options to appears me in the download clonezilla-live page, are these:

```
estables emisiones (.iso / .zip) - 2.1.1-7

clonezilla-live-20130314-quantal-i386
clonezilla-live-2.1.1-7-amd64.zip
clonezilla-live-2.1.1-7-amd64.iso
clonezilla-live-2.1.1-7-i486.zip
clonezilla-live-2.1.1-7-i486.iso
clonezilla-live-2.1.1-7-i686-pae.zip
clonezilla-live-2.1.1-7-i686-pae.iso
```

What is the difference between Clonezilla-live based on Debian, and the alternative one based on Ubuntu?.

I want burn Clonezilla-Live on a DVD, so I guess that the zip is dont to me, no?

What is the right to choose to me?

Thank you in advance any easy explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The version depends on your hardware, not on the operating systems you have installed. for example, you have Windows Vista 32 Bit and Ubuntu 12.10 64 Bit, which means that you have hardware that can either use 32 bit or 64 bit software. With that in mind let us look into your list:

```
clonezilla-live-2.1.1-7-amd64.zip
clonezilla-live-2.1.1-7-amd64.iso
clonezilla-live-2.1.1-7-i486.zip
clonezilla-live-2.1.1-7-i486.iso
clonezilla-live-2.1.1-7-i686-pae.zip
clonezilla-live-2.1.1-7-i686-pae.iso
```

Since what we want is to burn the image, we go with the **.iso** files which leaves us like this

```
clonezilla-live-2.1.1-7-amd64.iso
clonezilla-live-2.1.1-7-i486.iso
clonezilla-live-2.1.1-7-i686-pae.iso
```

Since you have a system that supports 64 Bit you can use the clonezilla-live-2.1.1-7-amd64.iso version. You can also use the i686-pae but it is better to use a 64 Bit version of a 64 Bit supported hardware.

Now, after downloading the 64 bit iso, do not worry about cloning a 32 bit Windows or Linux OS. Like I said before, the version to download depends on the hardware. So with the 64 Bit version you can clone either a 32 Bit version or a 64 Bit version of an OS installed without any problem.

Comment: Luis Alvarado Again thank you very much a lots, by this clear and complete informations, I apreciate a lots it, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use 64 bit ubuntu, you should be able to use 64 bit clonezilla. I've used both the debian and ubuntu versions, they are both pretty much the same as far as it concerns us.

Comment: So the right option to clone Ubuntu 12.10 64 bits, burning Clonezilla on DVD is: clonezilla-live-2.1.1-7-amd64.iso???. But what is the right version to clone windows vista 32 bitssss???Thank you

Comment: Because no Linux utility is worth using if you can't get 5 million flavours....

Comment: Ok Is good have millions of flavors, but I want know now how I taste the right clonezilla flavours